# What is Windows "hosts" file alternative for OSX?

Tags: macos, hosts-file

I just got a Mac computer (OSx v10.6) to test my web site design. Web site is running on the local network, and in windows computers I use "hosts" file to map its network IP address to domain name, like

```
192.168.1.7 www.sitename.com
```

How can I do that on Mac?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OSX does have a /etc/hosts file but it first uses directory services to find hosts. These are maintained via the dscl command

[This web page](http://tomafro.net/2009/07/dscl-the-easy-way-to-add-hosts-on-osx) provides examples of use to maintain the lookups.

Essentially, you just need to run the following command in Terminal:

```
sudo dscl localhost -create /Local/Default/Hosts/sitename.com IPAddress 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Added the most important information from the web page to your answer so it will still work even if that web site goes down or changed. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: Actually, directory services reads both /var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/computers/* (which DS calls /Local/Default/Hosts, and is where these instructions put host entries) and /etc/hosts (which DS calls /BSD/local/Hosts), so doing this is equivalent to making an entry in /etc/hosts.  (Although it checks dslocal before /etc/hosts, so if there's a conflict, that'll take precedence.)

Comment: @DanielBeck and the website went down. Thanks for adding that bit of info :)

Answer (score 5):

There's a `hosts` file in `/etc/`, a path you can access in Finder using the *Go » Go to Folder* menu item.

Right-click it and *Get Info* to change its permissions at the bottom, so you can edit it. You might also need to temporarily give yourself permissions for the parent folder `/etc` so saving works. It's a bit tricky with some GUI editors.

---

Alternatively, `sudo vim /etc/hosts` in Terminal, if you're comfortable with `vim` (or any other CLI editor).

[image]

The file itself works like you'd expect it to.

Comment: Ugh. Those colors. Sorry about that.

Comment: You're fired :-)

Comment: `You might also need to give yourself permissions for the parent folder /etc so saving works.` No, just no. That's the **worst** advice you can ever give to anyone.

Comment: @LieRyan I'd have expected it's obvious that any permissions users give themselves here should be taken away after everything works. Isn't it?

Comment: a lot easies than the accepted answer...