# Windows hosts file equivalent on Mac?

Tags: windows, macos, hosts-file

I am doing a project and uploading to a clients test server, however they only have IP address to access and suggested editing my hosts file. I'm on a Mac, where is the hosts file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is Windows "hosts" file alternative for OSX?](https://superuser.com/questions/245354/what-is-windows-hosts-file-alternative-for-osx)

Answer (score 23):

I'm going to get very liberal with your question....

I'm assuming they want you to add an entry to the hosts file.  You would find that in /private/etc/hosts on your Mac.

Here's a link -
http://decoding.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/how-to-edit-the-hosts-file-in-mac-os-x-leopard/